# Move files with SSIS (2013) to different directories dynamically based on filename expression

Tags: sql-server, ssis

If searched and searched but couldn't find the right answer:

I want to move textfiles using SSIS package (SQL-Server 2012)

The source of the files is in C:\TEMP

The destination of the files is in one of the following three directories:

1. C:\ARCHIVE\AAA\
2. C:\ARCHIVE\BBB\
3. C:\ARCHIVE\CCC\

The name of the files are randomly created by another proces and have an 8 digit filename like:12345678.txt, 45382746.txt, 99325555.txt

With the SSIS package I want to move files:

to C:\ARCHIVE\AAA\   -   when the first two digits of the filename are between 10 and 29.

to C:\ARCHIVE\BBB\   -   when the first two digits of the filename are between 30 and 59.

to C:\ARCHIVE\CCC\   -   when the first two digits of the filename are between 60 and 00.

I am trying to do this **without** a script task but only with a foreach loop container with a filesystem task inside using expressions.

I have a foreach loop container which loops through the different files and storing them into a variable user::CurrentFile
The problem I have is to dynamically move the files to the different (already existing) directories in the filesystem task.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you 'have to dynamically move the files to the different (already existing) directories in the filesystem task' ?

Comment: Because I think it is possible to do this without a script task. I'm not very good at scripting and it must be possible I think.

Comment: But if a scripting task is just the way to do it I'm OK with that too. As a DBA I'm more confident with expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression to choose destination path (in File System Task), verifies that the first two digits in the file name are in the useful range, returning the correct path: 
(eg C:\ARCHIVE\AAA\ when the first two digits of the filename are between 10 and 29 or ...)

```
(DT_I4)(LEFT(@[User::CurrentFile],2)) >= 10 && (DT_I4)(LEFT(@[User::CurrentFile],2)) <= 29 ? "C:\\ARCHIVE\\AAA\\" : (DT_I4)(LEFT(@[User::CurrentFile],2)) >= 30 && (DT_I4)(LEFT(@[User::CurrentFile],2)) <= 59 ? "C:\\ARCHIVE\\BBB\\" : (DT_I4)(LEFT(@[User::CurrentFile],2)) >= 60 && (DT_I4)(LEFT(@[User::CurrentFile],2)) <= 99 ? "C:\\ARCHIVE\\CCC\\" : (DT_WSTR, 2)(LEFT(@[User::CurrentFile],2)) == "00" ? "C:\\ARCHIVE\\CCC\\" :  ""
```

supposing that @[User::CurrentFile] just contains the name of the file eg 12345678.txt; in the latter case I have considered the values >= 60 and  <= 99 or == "00" (understood as a string for the double zero).

This expression must be added to a global variable; the variable will be chosen in the File System Task such as "destination".

The expression does not check whether the two characters are integers, for this task we should add another control.

I hope this help.

Comment: It puts me in the right direction that is for sure. But when the first 'case' is set tot C:\\ARCHIVE\AAA it holds this value in the destination variable and puts all the files in this directory. Next to the fact that the (DT_I4) gives a casting error on the @[User::CurrentFile]. Even if for testing reasons I only put 3 files in the TEMP directory (10000000.txt, 35000000.txt and 65000000.txt)

Comment: Can you check the CurrentFile value passed inside the loop?

Comment: Thanks Alex that was indeed the probleem. In production code the network path included two "\\"  So I made another variable (FileName) to extract those. RIGHT(@[User::CurrentFile], FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::CurrentFile]),"\\",1) -1 ). I used this variable in the expression you helped me with: ( (DT_I4)  LEFT(@[User::FIleName] ,2)) <= 35 ? @[User::AAADestination]  :  @[User::BBBDestination]. The last snipped is just a part of the whole expression but so you know what I mean.  Thanks again!